# I want to remove the word "item/items" from cart in the navbar in Sylius

Tags: sylius

I want to remove the word "item/items" in Sylius navbar. Want only item number with cart icon.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/f09571149926d5cee76030d4947434ddcbcb829a/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/views/Cart/_widget.html.twig#L10 template and remove this line (line 10):

```
{% transchoice cart.items|length %}sylius.ui.item.choice{% endtranschoice %}
```

UPDATE

write instead of that line `{{ cart.items|length }}`

[Info about template overriding](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.3/customization/template.html#how-to-customize-templates-by-overriding)

Comment: I tried removing this line. I want to remove the word "item/items" only but Its also removing the number of items in the cart.

Comment: @SimranMalhotra write instead that line `{{ cart.items|length }}`

Comment: @SimranMalhotra please mark my answer as solved your question, I updated it :)